# Meaning of the context : aggregate diffusion processes for technological innovations

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The objective of this paper is to better understand the nature and role of Leading Edge Users in the individual adoption and **aggregate diffusion processes for technological innovations**.

What does "aggregate diffusion processes for technological innovations" mean,
Does it mean "combining the diffusion processes",
and "for technological innovations" explains what kind of **processes**?

And I think **for** is attached to **processes**,
so does the meaning still remain the same if **for** is replaced with **of**?

Comment: The title of the question "Meaning of the phrase", is not a good title. It doesn't help people to know what the question is about.  Try to edit the title to make it better.

Comment: @JamesK Thanks, I edited the title to make it more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sentence, "aggregate diffusion" is in contrast to "individual adoption".   These are two types of process (for "technological innovations")

The paper is about the role of "Leading Edge Users"  (this phrase is capitalised, which suggests it is a jargon term in this industry) in the "individual adoption process" and the role of "Leading Edge Users" in the "aggregate diffusion process".  These two processes are "processes for technological innovations".

However I do not know the jargon, so I don't know what "Leading Edge Users" actually means.  Nor do I know what an "aggregate diffusion process" actually is. It must have some special meaning.

Comment: I think "aggregate diffusion" means the spread of these innovations across the entire community involved, as opposed to their adoption by individuals.